# Maven can't find my offline dependencies / local artifacts ("not available in the local repository")?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to download all my depenandies and have them available offline, but when I run `mvn -o test`, it says `The repository system is offline but the artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 is not available in the local repository`. However, I have this package in my `~/.m2/repository`!

## `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>true</offline>
</settings>
```

## `ls ~/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/`

```
 _maven.repositories
 commons-io-2.4.jar
 commons-io-2.4.jar.lastUpdated
 commons-io-2.4.jar.sha1
 commons-io-2.4.pom
 commons-io-2.4.pom.sha1
```

## mvn -o test

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2.0.2:generateRunners
>   (generateRunners) on project myproject: Execution
>   generateRunners of goal
>   com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2.0.2:generateRunners
>   failed: Plugin com.github.temyers:cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin:2.0.2
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
>
> The repository
>   system is offline but the artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 is
>   not available in the local repository. -> [Help 1]

## The problem

Basically **maven says I don't have ~/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/, but I *do*!**

I tried this:

```
find ~/.m2/repository -name _maven.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;
```

but after **deleting `_maven.repositories`**, when I ran `mvn -o test`, **the file came right back**!

I have maven `3.0.5`

Comment: Remove `commons-io-2.4.jar.lastUpdated`, and you should be good to go. Alternatively, update Maven, as I don't think 3.3.9 will try to download things in offline mode, even with the presence of this file.

Comment: @Tunaki I removed `commons-io-2.4.jar.lastUpdated` and it still had the error :/ I tried removing it and `_maven.repositories` and got the same thing. When I run `mvn test -o` they both come back

Comment: Oh wait! it's working! Thanks @Tunaki !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These 3 things got it to work (thanks to @Tunaki)

1. **Put `-o` at the END of your mvn command.** Example `mvn test -o`. When I used it at the beginning, it didn't work
2. **Delete all `*.lastUpdated` files.**

   - `find ~/.m2/repository -name *.lastUpdated -exec rm -v {} \;`
3. **Delete all `_maven.repositories` files.**

   - `find ~/.m2/repository -name _maven.repositories -exec rm -v {} \;`

***Note***: the `settings.xml` made no difference whether it was there or removed. So I don't think it did anything.

Comment: The position of the `-o` really shouldn't change anything.

Comment: I had to also delete the *.sha1 files.